# wxPython. Canvas de Matplotlib afecta apariencia de otros widgets

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, wxpython

Con el siguiente código obtengo la figura que le sigue:

```
import wx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx


class VentanaPrincipal(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self,None,-1,'',size=(500,300))

        # Barra de menu
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(wx.Menu(), "Archivo")
        menuBar.Append(wx.Menu(), "Ayuda")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        splt_prin = wx.SplitterWindow(self,style=wx.SP_BORDER)

        # Panel Notebook
        pnl_nb = wx.Panel(splt_prin)
        siz_nb = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        nb = wx.Notebook(pnl_nb,-1,style=wx.NB_TOP)
        nb.AddPage(wx.TextCtrl(nb,-1,'Datos...'),'DATOS')
        siz_nb.Add(nb,1,wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT,5)
        pnl_nb.SetSizer(siz_nb)

        # Panel ploteo
        pnl_plot = wx.Panel(splt_prin)
        siz_plot = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        canvas,toolbar = mplCanvas(pnl_plot)
        siz_plot.Add(canvas,1,wx.EXPAND); siz_plot.Add(toolbar)

        coords = wx.StaticText(pnl_plot,-1,'Coordenadas...')
        siz_plot.Add(coords,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        pnl_plot.SetSizer(siz_plot)

        splt_prin.SplitVertically(pnl_nb,pnl_plot)
        splt_prin.SetMinimumPaneSize(150)

def mplCanvas(parent_canvas):
    figura = plt.figure()
    ax = figura.add_subplot(111)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(parent_canvas,-1,figura)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Wx(canvas)
    return canvas,toolbar

class Aplicacion(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = VentanaPrincipal()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Aplicacion(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, hay una problema en la barra de menús. Este problema no lo tengo cuando no agrego el canvas, pues la barra de menús aparece como debiera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué el canvas afecta la apariencia de la barra de menús? Al parecer también afecta la apariencia de los otros widgets.

Su ayuda sería muy valiosa. Gracias.

Comment: No se si será la causa directa ya que en mi caso bajo sistema Linux (dónde Wx usa Gtk) ocasiona directamente un SegmentFault pero debería ser `figura = plt.Figure()` no `figura = plt.figure()`, corrigiendo eso en mi caso la app se muestra como debe.

Comment: Sí, funcionó! Muchas gracias! De paso se solucionaron otros comportamientos extraños a los que no encontraba su causa. Muchas gracias de verdad. Saludos.